# PHP xml signature cannot verify in .NET (c#)

Tags: xml, digital-signature

I try to generate xml signature in php using this [lib](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs)

but generated xml signature coud not be verified by the .NET (c#).

signature generated by php has ds prefix on signature tag.

like this

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

but when I generate signature in c# with same algorithm (rsa sha1) this tag looks like this

`<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">`

I coud not understand what the problem is or how to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of class XMLSecurityDSig accepts a parameter for the namespace called *$prefix* that defaults to "ds", if you provide an empty string the prefix  vanishes.

**Constructor:**

```
/**
 * @param string $prefix
 */
public function __construct($prefix='ds')
{
    var_dump($prefix);
    $template = self::BASE_TEMPLATE;
    if (! empty($prefix)) {
        $this->prefix = $prefix.':';
        $search = array("<S", "</S", "xmlns=");
        $replace = array("<$prefix:S", "</$prefix:S", "xmlns:$prefix=");
        $template = str_replace($search, $replace, $template);
    }
    $sigdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $sigdoc->loadXML($template);
    $this->sigNode = $sigdoc->documentElement;
}
```

**Example:**

```
$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig("");
```

Greets
Robin